# Set focus to end of string in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with an attribute `contenteditable` and I want so cut the content that's input and is longer than e.g. 5 chars. But the focus is set to start of the input all the time...

```js
var maxlength = 5;
$(".test").attr("contenteditable", function(){
    $(this).on('keyup', function( e ){
        if( $(this).html().length > (maxlength)){
            var content = $(this).html();
                content = content.substring(0,(maxlength));
            $(this).html(content).focus();
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

```css
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

How can I set the cursor to the end of the div content?

I found some samples here in SO but they all did not work for my construct.

I have tried `.focus()` and also with `.blur()` before and cleared content... no results...

Of course I don't want to install a Plugin...

Comment: Altering the content as part of the event like that is rather messy… why don't you use the `keypress` event, and cancel it if the length exceeds the maximum? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278540/maxlength-in-textarea-using-jquery

Comment: this could be a way... ill test this

Comment: @cmbuckley post this as an answere and ill accapt it! :D this brought me to the right thing :)

Comment: Glad it helped, but I'll suggest that it's marked as a duplicate rather than taking all of the credit :-)

Comment: Actually its not a duplicate. The other post is about textareas and they have a different behavior than divs does. Sometimes answere are similar but the mean diffrent things. So for me its not duplicate and you gave the correct answere with that hint. But thats very kind of you thinking like this!

Comment: No worries! To be honest I think it's better that the hint sent you in the right direction and you got to the answer yourself!

Answer (score 2):

My Solution:

```js
$('.test').attr('contenteditable', function() {
  $(this).on('keypress', function(e) {
    var len = $(this).attr('maxlength');
    if ($(this).html().length >= len) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  return true;
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
}
.small {
  width: 42px;
}
.medium {
  width: 82px;
}
.large {
  width: 122px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
MaxLength 5:
<div class="test small" maxlength="5"></div>
MaxLength 10:
<div class="test medium" maxlength="10"></div>
MaxLength 15:
<div class="test large" maxlength="15"></div>
```

thx to @cmbuckley. Brought me to the new thinking :D

No focus needed because the focus is never lost and chars can be deleted easy.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to moce the carret, here is a question about this :

[Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox)

Comment: the thing is.. i am testing this in jsfiddle and allways get errors when using createtextrange stuff...

Comment: I think this is because you are using a <div> instead of a <input> or <textarea>. The best solution would be using a <input type="text"> with a maximum length allows. I would'nt even require javascript

Comment: Using an input is not the task :) I know how to do it with the input but in my case I have to use div. But the comment of @cmbuckley brought me to the right solution. Thx anyways :)

Comment: I think his answer is the correctone too if you cannot user inputs :)