# Setting min length in input text is giving repetitive alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a user to add minimum 10 characters into the html `text`. So for that I have set a validation on `onblur` of the textbox. Below is the html and its JS code

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtStoreSiteAsstMangrMob"  maxlength="10" onblur="checkLength(this)"  onkeypress="return IsNumeric4(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function checkLength(el) {    
if (el.value.length != 10) {
    alert("Minimum 10 numbers are accepted");        
}  }
```

The problem here is that the validation is firing properly but the message is showing repetitively, even after clicking OK also.

So why is it happening like this?

Comment: it works. https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/QromYV?editors=1111 . so it's caused by something that you haven't show us

Comment: @JacobGoh: I have shown everything, it works even at my side also. But the alert is firing repetitively..

Comment: @BramVanroy: Sure, will keep this in mind for future

Comment: For me its working fine. Maybe the issue is something else which you have not mentioned here.

Comment: @HarshJaswal: I will try once again and check

Comment: And also the condition inside `if` statement should be like `el.value.length < 10` not like `el.value.length != 10`

Comment: @HarshJaswal: can u tell me how should I focus after alert in my code ?

Comment: @JacobGoh: I guess setting it focus after alert is causing the issue.. here is what I wrote for focus `el.focus();`

Comment: Try without focus once

Comment: yes without focus its working perfectly fine..SO now what should I do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171531/discussion-between-harsh-jaswal-and-bnn).

Answer (score 1):

Try below fiddle demo and it will clear you requirement:

HTML:

```
 <input type='text' id='text'/>
```

JS:

```
function textLength(value){
  var maxLength = 10;
  if(value.length > maxLength) return false;
  return true;
}

document.getElementById('text').onkeyup = function(){
 if(!textLength(this.value)) alert('text is too long!');
}
```

[Setting min length in input text is giving repetitive alert message](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/L2LRK/)

I Found here:

[Counting input chars - use onkeyup or onkeydown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165273/counting-input-chars-use-onkeyup-or-onkeydown)

Answer (score 0):

you use `el.value.length != 10`, that means if length greater then 10 then message will show if less than 10 then also message will show.

In your code if the input have exactly length 10 message then message will not show.

But you want check if length < 10 then show message and if more then 10 then don't show anything.

So I think better to use :

```
el.value.length < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkLength(el) {
  if (el.value.length != 10) {
    alert("Minimum 10 numbers are accepted");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtStoreSiteAsstMangrMob" maxlength="10" onblur="checkLength(this)" onkeypress="return IsNumeric4(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" />
</body>

</html>
```

your code is working fine for me.. please check again..
As per my understanding, if we use input field validations using onBlur function, focus may trouble you with this type of problems..

Answer (score 0):

Using `onblur` event handler on more than one inputs, can result the same thing, result may vary browser to browser.

Option 1: Avoid using js alert() with onblur.

Option 2: Put basic validations on form submit instead of input blur.

Comment: `Using onblur event handler on more than one inputs, can result the same thing.` I am just showing you that this point is invalid

Answer (score 0):

here's a way to make it work when you want to keep re-focusing it

demo https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/PeLaRw?editors=1011

save the state in the elem's data attribute, for e.g. `data-should-alert`, set it to false after alerting once so that the function can decide where or not to alert again. set it to true again once the user start typing something.

```
function checkLength(el) {
  if(el.getAttribute('data-should-alert')==='false') return;
  if (el.value.length != 10) {
    alert("Minimum 10 numbers are accepted");
    el.setAttribute('data-should-alert', 'false');
    el.focus();
  } 
}

function handleKeydown(el) {
    el.setAttribute('data-should-alert', 'true');
}
```

Comment: @BNN in that case, a global variable is not suitable. the state can be stored inside each element's data attribute. answer updated

Comment: Actually its surprising, because `alert` is synchronous so script waits until the alert dialog to be closed to keep on. So in that case `el.focus()` should work only after the user clicks on the ok button of alert box.

Comment: @HarshJaswal I think it's still synchronous. But something is causing the input to blur immediately after focus. I wonder what it could be

Comment: It is behaving like a `recursion`, which turned into a never ending loop. focus...blur...focus..blur and so on....