# jQuery Text Field Value Change, Bind Function

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to bind the change event for a text field in jQuery? I.E. whenever the value changes, call some function? I am currently using `keyup` but that doesn't hit every case, i.e. right click and paste.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823733/textarea-onchange-detection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect all changes to a <input type="text"> (immediately) using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery)

Answer (score 11):

```
$("#element").bind("keyup input paste", function() {
    //Do Work Here
});
```

Comment: This is nice, but what's the difference in outcome if you don't `bind` to `paste`? (I see how `keyup` makes sense for older browsers.)

Comment: Just for the record. I wanted to validate a text field every time its value changes. `keyup` doesn't works as expected, because if the user type CTRL+V, the event was called twice. Now I'm using only `bind("input", function() {`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the change() trigger?

```
$('.target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: .change() only appears to be triggered when losing focus (blur), at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

keyup seems to work for me with copy and paste, at least in Firefox.  Where do you see the problem?  Which browser?  Can you post an example?

http://jsfiddle.net/9fJwC/

Comment: Yeah copy some text, then click into the field, right click and paste. Notice the text is NOT updated.

Comment: OK I see what you mean.  I can hit Ctrl-V to paste and it works, but right-click and Paste doesn't.  Even when the input loses the focus.  That's some strange behavior.