# MutationObserver working example? FF or Chrome

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I've created a JSfiddle example of how I'd like to test MutationObserver. dead simple.
http://jsfiddle.net/bqcpna3k/6/

HTML

```
<div>
 <input name='a' value='1'>
 <input name='b' value='1'>
 <input name='c' value='1'>
 <input name='d' value='1'>
 <input name='e' value='1'>
 <input name='f' value='1'>
</div>

<div>
<p>would like to update the labels from mutationobserver function</p>

a <label id='a'></label>
b <label id='b'></label>
c <label id='c'></label>
d <label id='d'></label>
e <label id='e'></label>
f <label id='f'></label>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var inputs=[];

//decide which inputs to give interesting changing numbers to
$('input').each(function(i,e){
    if (Math.random()>0.5) inputs.push(e); else e.value='ignore';
});

//change the special input boxes numbers regularly
setInterval(function() {
    inputs.forEach(function(e){e.value=Math.floor(Math.random()*50);});
},1000);

//this function is supposed to run reliably when the numbers change
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

//var target = $('input').closest('div')[0]; //have never had any success in getting Mutation Events to fire when trying to observe a div
var target = document.body;//simple

//activate the MutationObserver
observer.observe(target, { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true });

console.log('finished staring up');
```

CSS

```
label {display:block}
```

In other testing I've had problems getting the MutationObserver function to run reliably. I also had problems observing a div instead of document.body.

In the above fiddle, the MutationObserver function doesn't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see that input values are not part of the DOM or their updates don't reflect in the DOM, so this won't work.

Someone gave me a link to a similar question now
[How do you get a mutation observer to detect a value change of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048645/how-do-you-get-a-mutation-observer-to-detect-a-value-change-of-a-textarea)