# How to show max words can be entered in text-area in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am working on one PHP form where i am putting a text-area field. Maximum 500 words can be inputted into the text-area field. I am displaying that value with label.

Here what i want to do is while the user types into the text-area field the total entered words should get subtracted from max words and that value should appear live.

For example if i have entered the text "I" than the value of max words should get changed to 499.

So how can i execute it.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: 500 times _"superfragilisticexpialidocious"_, or do you mean letters?

Comment: I would suggest using JavaScript instead of sending `textarea` content each time to php just to count words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html Code

```
<textarea id="field"></textarea>
<div id="charNum">0</div>
```

Jquery code

```
$("#field").keyup(function(){
el = $(this);
if(el.val().length >= 500){
    el.val( el.val().substr(0, 500) );
} else {
    $("#charNum").text(500-el.val().length);
}
});
```

Working example
   http://jsfiddle.net/vikastyagi87/xqyWV/255/

Comment: He wants words. Not letters.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need ajax to do this. Just use a script on the page for far less overhead, for example:

HTML:

```
<!-- create textarea and limit characters -->
<textarea id="input" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="500"> 
</textarea>
<span id="output"></span>
```

JS:

```
var maxWords = 500;
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

output.innerHTML = maxWords + " words left";

input.onkeyup = function() {
    var words = input.value.split(" "); // Convert string into words
    var diff = maxWords - words.length; // Subtract words from maxWords
    if (diff < 0) { // If words < maxWords prevent user from inputting more than maxWords
        words.length = maxWords; // Remove words over limit
        input.value = words.join(" "); // Fill input
        diff = 0;
    }
    output.innerHTML = diff + " words left"; // Tell user new word count
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/georeith/z2KfV/2/

This doesn't take into account the complexities of language however and assumes that any space denotes a new word. If you want it to do those things you will have to look into using regex.

*For a max character version see: http://jsfiddle.net/georeith/z2KfV/4/*

Comment: He wants words. Not letters.

Comment: @silvinci Just realised and updated

Comment: Please use `string.match(/\w+/g).length`, as repeatead whitespaces would break your algorithm. Also, don't permit users typing as this makes a terrible UX. Just permit the submitting.

Comment: @silvinci That was mentioned in my answer, the rest is up to the OP to play with and discover.

Comment: Sorry, overread that. Still `w+` is faster and works (at least) as well as the `.split(" ")` solution. Can you change that for the Googlers who come here? kthxbye

Answer (score 1):

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sCj3P/2/)

```
$(function() {
    $("textarea").keypress(function() {
        total_words = this.value.split(/[\s\.\?]+/).length;     
        $("p").html(500 - total_words); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Plese try this :)

```
<?php $no_of_word = 500;?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wordcount').keyup(function(){
        var totalword = $(this).val().length;
        if(totalword > <?php echo $no_of_word;?>){
            alert('Max word exceeded');
            $(this).attr('value',$(this).val().substr(0,<?php echo $no_of_word?>));
            $('#textrem').html(0);
        }else{
            var remword = <?php echo $no_of_word;?> - totalword;
            $('#textrem').html(remword);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<label>No of word remaining</label> <span id='textrem'><?php echo $no_of_word?></span>
<textarea id='wordcount'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in Javascript.
Count the number of space into your textarea (one space = on word), using regular expression.
And you display the substraction: maxWords-words

Answer (score 0):

In order to update an element on the screen each time the user types a letter, you'll have to use a combination of Javascript and HTML DOM.

JQuery simplifies it a bit: http://api.jquery.com/text/

You would need to capture the typing into the textarea with a Javascript event, which is actually a little more complicated.

Look at this thread for some information: [Textarea onchange detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823733/textarea-onchange-detection)

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of words of a string use this:

```
var string = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
  , words = string.match(/\w+/g)  // ["lorem", "ipsum", ...]
  , numberOfWords = words.length; // 5
```

Or as a one liner: `"lorem ipsum".match(/\w+/g).length;`

You need to add this check to the onKeyup and onChange event of the textarea.