# Textarea on change submit form jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form for translating text and would like to have the form submit as the user enters characters. Similar to google translate.

Here is code sample:

```
<form id="trans" method="post" action="prevedi.php">
<textarea id="prevedi" name="prevedi" style="margin: 2px; height: 137px; width: 380px;"></textarea>
<textarea id="prevod" disabled="disabled" name="prevod" style="margin: 2px; height: 137px; width: 380px; border: 0px;" readonly></textarea>
<input name="translate" type="submit" value="Translate"/>
```

Any idea, how to do this?

Comment: Possibly similar issue as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823733/textarea-onchange-detection) in StackOverflow

Comment: Are you wanting to return a translation to another textarea or div as well? on change will input the form every time a letter gets typed, you might want to think about that as well and do an on blur or something so it only inputs after a complete change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#prevedi").change(function(){$("form").post();});});
```

Comment: Sorry, i change form, can you please edit your answer.

Comment: if that is the only form in the page then no need to change the code.

Comment: then try this: $(document).ready(function(){$("#prevedi").change(function(){$("#trans").post();});});

Comment: and remember to add link to jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#texterea#prevedi').on('keyup',function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: url,
     dataType: 'json',
     type: "post",
     data: {'word',$(this).val()},

     success: function (result) {
       $('#texterea#prevod').val(result.value);
     },
     error: function (error) {

     }
   });

 });
```

Comment: Sorry, i change form, can you please edit your answer.

Comment: What is `#tseterea#prevod`?

Comment: Sorry, texterea, you can also use #prevod without the word texterea.