# Detecting paste action into textarea and keeping word count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have been working on a plugin for the last couple of days. The plugin is simple, get the word count inside of a textarea. That's it. Now here's the problems I've been having:

- can not properly get word count after data is pasted
- discovered when text is pasted there is a time out, so a workaround with that has been very difficult to find.

I have tried just about everything, so I took a break from it, came back to it, and once again I give up, haha! I will post the code below and a link to the fiddle as well that I have been work with.

```
!function($){
    var TextareaWordCount = function(element, options){
        this.$element = element;
        this.options = options;
        this.defaults = {
            limit : 100
        };
    }
    TextareaWordCount.prototype = {
        constructor : TextareaWordCount,
        init : function(){
            var that = this,
            obj = this.$element,
            wordcount;
            this.options = $.extend(this.defaults, this.options);
            this.detectPaste();
        },
        getWordCount : function(words){
            var words_array = words.split(/\S+/g);
            console.log(words_array);
            return words_array.length;
        },
        trimParagraph : function(){
            var element = this.$element;
            var options = this.options; //get the global options
            var words = $(element).text().split(/\S+/);
            words = words.splice(0, options.limit);
            var content = words.join(" ");
            $(element).val(content);
        },
        detectPaste : function(){
            var that = this;
            var element = this.$element;

            $(element).bind({
                paste : function(){
                    var words;
                    function first(){
                        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            words = element.val();
                            resolve("pasted");

                        }, 100);
                    });
                    }
                    first().then(function(){
                        console.log(words);
                        var count = that.getWordCount(words);
                        if(count > that.options.limit){
                        //  that.trimParagraph(element);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        'onKeyPress' : function(){

        }
    };
    $.fn.textareaWordCount = function(){
        var _data = null;
        if(arguments.length){
            _data = arguments[0];
        }
        var _TextareaWordCount = new TextareaWordCount(this, _data);
        _TextareaWordCount.init();
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.textareaWordCount.Constructor = TextareaWordCount;

}( window.jQuery );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ouhey3vd/118/

Comment: You don't have to explicitly hook a paste event, as pasted text will trigger change events. For more information, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript/1125521#1125521 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823733/textarea-onchange-detection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going on a really really wrong path.
Instead of doing all that crazy over-complicated stuff, why don't you use the native textarea element events ?

I know the following code is very different to yours, but for the sake of simplicity, this is a very easy way to implement a word count.

[Link to Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ouhey3vd/122/)

```
var textArea = $('#text');
var textAreaInfo = $('#textInfo');

function countWords(){
    textAreaInfo.html(textArea.val().split(/\S+/g).length-1);
}

textArea.keyup(function(){
   countWords();
});
```

This won't listen for mouse events, but it's so easy to add.

Note: Using a timeout to wait for the paste event is actually a **really bad** idea. This is heavily under-optimized, & the timeout you are talking about may significantly vary depending on the computer's specs. Sometimes 100ms won't be enough, especially when the pasted text is huge.

Comment: so you're saying don't worry about the paste function just check the events of mouse up, key up, etc...

Comment: Basically, yes. This is event-based programming.
Instead of checking the content at regular intervals, you should definitively listen for events. And -special tip-, there is even a 'paste' event ! (http://jsfiddle.net/ouhey3vd/124/)