# how to get textContent of textarea after change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textarea` tag. I want to be able to get its `textContent` after `textContent` changed?

```
<textarea id="xxx"> sameple text </textarea> // before
<textarea id="xxx"> sameple text and new text </textarea> // after
```

I want listen even when the `textarea`'s content has changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textarea onchange detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823733/textarea-onchange-detection)

Answer (score 1):

you can put your script as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#xxx").change(function(){
     alert($("#xxx").val());
  });
});
```

if you put `$("#xxx").html()` it will give you before text but if you keep `$("#xxx").val()` it will give you changed value.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use onkeyup and onchange for this. The onchange will prevent context-menu pasting, and the onkeyup will fire for every keystroke.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).on('change','#xxx',function(){
             var newtext = $(this).text();
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use [**`input`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event.

*The `DOM` `input event` is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.*

```js
$('#xxx').on('input', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="xxx">sameple text</textarea>
```