# How to count the number of characters entered in a text box and display it automatically next to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm searching for the following event, I need the number of the characters entered into a text box in a registration screen to appear automatically next to the same text box in JavaScript or jQuery.

it's a question from a beginner, thanks in advance.

Comment: search of `.keyup()` then get the `length` of the `.val()` of input

Comment: @guradio `.keyup()` is not a reliable function for this. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823733/textarea-onchange-detection

Comment: @MasterBob in your link did you read it?the answer used `.keyup()`

Comment: @guradio *facepalm*... does anybody read the comments these days?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Listen for the `input` event and check the length of the textbox's value then.

```js
$("#input").on("input", function() {
    $("#count").text(this.value.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input"> <span id="count">0</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, keypress should be the ideal event to look for character count.

```
$('#input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var count = $(this).val().length;
    $('#span').text(count);
})
```

**Keypress vs. Keyup:**

If i press and hold any character key for a few seconds, it'd enter few characters in input box and keyup event would give you a count of 1 for this because key was lifted only once. However, keypress would give the exact number of characters entered.

Comment: What if I edit the text via the *Edit* menu rather than the keyboard? (Also, your explanation about not using `keyup` doesn't quite make sense, because the code you've shown doesn't count how many times the key was pressed/lifted, it directly tests the length of the current value.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I didn't get editing text via Edit menu. Also, my explanation was not entirely in context of the question. May be my way of telling this was wrong but what i intended to tell is how keyup differs from keypress.