# How to take inputs from users in the textarea, and display the written string through textContent in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If i am adding the change eventListener it take the value as a change i want to take a string through textarea and display it with textContent on HTML page, Please Help!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textarea onchange detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823733/textarea-onchange-detection)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="2">

<p>Click the button to change the number of the number field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> input elements with type="number" are not supported in IE 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myNumber").value = "16";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

kinda hard to get into the question. did you mean something like this?

```
document.getElementById('textarea').addEventListener('change', e => {
    div.textContent = e.target.value;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p7f8v6no/10/