# Text Area maxlength not working

Tags: html

I want to set maximum length to the textarea. I am using following code for the same,but it is not working,

```
<textarea name="txtDescription" cols=10 rows=3 maxlength=50></textarea>
```

But it is not working,it takes characters beyond 50.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to impose maxlength on textArea in HTML , Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `maxlength` attribute defined for `textarea`. You need to [implement](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=textarea+limit+characters&aq=f&aqi=g3g-m2&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=8631cdd35a4d476d) this [using javascript](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html).

Comment: Your own "implement" link says it's supported for HTML5.

Comment: @AminAriana it is now, where it wasn't when this answer was created and accepted.

Comment: `textarea` does have [maxlength](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-textarea-element.html#attr-textarea-maxlength) now.

Answer (score 4):

Yup maxlength does not work in textarea. But you can use jQuery something like this:

```
var $limitNum = 500;
$('textarea[name="textarea_name"]').keydown(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.val().length > $limitNum) {
        $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $limitNum));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When the answer of Darin Dimitrov was posted back in 2010, the `maxlength` attribute wasn't implemented apparently.

Right know, in 2018, it is.

**Sources**

- [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=maxlength)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-form)

**Example**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <label for="without">Without maxlength</label>
  <textarea id="without" class="form-control"></textarea>
  <br>
  <label for="with">With maxlength="10"</label>
  <textarea id="with" maxlength="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: But as you see its not working properly if you break lines you get the result that value.length < maxLength - this is the issue here :/ If you have any better solution, will be glad to hear. thanks!

Comment: @Vano I Use Chrome and I can't type more than 10 break lines or for example 5 break lines and 5 characters (I assume you mean pressing the Enter key?)

Comment: Yes, the issue happens when you press enter, in Chrome it works fine but on Safari it doesn't. So basically if you limit textarea let's say maxLength=100 and you press enter 5 times, when you reach max limit - you end up that textarea value.length === 95.

Comment: @Vano I see what you mean. If you want to prevent that, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004311/textarea-val-length-not-counting-enter-line-breaks-in-chrome). It is a “problem” with JavaScript, but can be worked around.

Answer (score 2):

I tried maxlength in textarea, but does not count the characters correctly(also counts the EOLs).
I use `max_length` attribute instead of normal `maxlength`.

HTML:

```
<textarea name="whatever" max_length="100"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
  var maxlength = parseInt($(this).attr('max_length')),
      text = $(this).val(),
      eol = text.match(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g),
      count_eol = $.isArray(eol) ? eol.length : 0,//error if eol is null
      count_chars = text.length - count_eol;
  if (maxlength && count_chars > maxlength)
    $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxlength + count_eol));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers above are correct for earlier version of IE 10.

If you are having problem with maxlength attribure, my recommendation is check your browser version first. The maxlength attribute is new for the  tag in HTML5. It should be just fine on IE 10+ or Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Maxlength attribute for textarea works in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

**you can use**

```
<textarea name="testString" onkeypress="if (this.value.length >= 250) { return false; }"id="" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="250"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to put it into the HTML tag like this, make sure you have airquotes "".

```html
<textarea maxlength="5"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -3):

This works for Ruby on Rails :

```
:maxlength => "10"
```

code example:

```
<%= text_area 'order', 'special_instructions_display', :size => "85x7", :maxlength => "10"  %>
```

Answer (score -4):

please use jquery for reference

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$().ready(function(){   

     $("#textareaId").attr('maxlength','20');   

 });
</script>
```

Comment: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'maxLength'