# Textarea | val().length not counting "Enter/Line Breaks" in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, textarea, maxlength

I have a `textarea` with the attribute `maxlength` set to `350` & it works fine, it also counts enter/line break as a character.

I also have to show a error message if user try to type more than or reaches to `350` character limit for which I am using this code:

```
$("textarea").keyup(function (e) {
    if($(this).val().length >=350){
        $('.error').show();
    }else{
        $('.error').hide();
    }
});
```

It works but in chrome it doesn't count enter/line break but maxlength does as a result if a user is breaking text in multiple lines, he do stops typing after 350 character but don't see any message.

Here is a fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/udp9oxx4/

Note this bug only occurs in chrome.

Comment: yes it is showing the msg over 350 charecters in chrome

Comment: I was just burned by this one. As you said, the value of textarea doesn't  include CR/LFs. I had some code that passed the client validation but it failed on the server because the value had more characters than allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("textarea").keyup(function (e) {

var isChrome = window.chrome;
if(isChrome){
var value = $(this).val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"  ");
}
else{
var value = $(this).val();
}

        if(value.length >=350){
            $('.error').show();
        }else{
            $('.error').hide();
        }
    });
```

Chrome counts line break as 2 character, so it counts the characters wrong. Just add this code in front of the function and it will work just fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/3wpqd4nr/

Fiddle

Comment: Thanks, I just tested my fiddle on mac safari as well and the bug is there too, should add a condition for `window.safari` as well, I guess it has to do something with chrome and safari javascript engine.

Comment: I am a little busy right now, but we will have to find if this is a js engine issue and if so the condition should be based on js engine.

Comment: this answer is no more valid

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam why?