# Limit all textarea to specified number of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

On the page there are number of text area. The number is dynamic not fixed. I need to limit length of all text areas on one page. How can I do this in js or jquery?

---

My try:-

```
<body>
        <div id="contact">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr class="questionsView" style="width: 100%;margin: 5px;">
                            <td class="mandatory">
                                <b>1&nbsp;
                                    *Qywerew we</b>
                                <hr/>
                                <table class="profileTable" style="margin-left: 25px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <textarea style="border: solid 1px #800000;" rows="5" name="165" cols="100">
                                            </textarea>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="questionsView" style="width: 100%;margin: 5px;">
                            <td class="">
                                <b>2&nbsp;
                                    a da da da</b>
                                <hr/>
                                <table class="profileTable" style="margin-left: 25px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <textarea style="border: solid 1px #800000;" rows="5" name="166" cols="100">
                                            </textarea>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return checkThis()">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('textarea').bind('paste keyup blur', function(){
                $(this).val(function(i, val){
                    return val.substr(0, 5);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: I've recently had the same task and couldn't find anything reliable across all browsers. Specifically, I had a problem of pasting the text using the right-click context menu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to impose maxlength on textArea in HTML using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('textarea').bind('paste keyup blur', function() {
    $(this).val(function(i, val) {
        return val.substr(0, 5);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xn65D/).

#### Update

> I don't know why but it prints `function(i, val) { return val.substr(0, 5); }` in text area every time.

Sounds like you are using an older version of jQuery (pre `1.4`). The refactored code below will work.

```
$('textarea').bind('paste keyup blur', function() {
    $(this).val(this.value.substr(0, 5));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZDwQ/).

The previous code would not work prior to jQuery 1.4 because it expected a string only as the argument to `val()`. By passing a function, its `toString()` was implicitly called, returning the string representation of the function.

Comment: I'd make it `.bind('paste keyup blur', ...)` - I've used code similar to yours in the past but I find cross-browser support for the `paste` event is a bit sketchy and drag'n'drop doesn't trigger paste or keyup. Adding in `blur` catches everything that gets by the other events, even if a little late.

Comment: It isn't working for me either. Specifically, I can paste long test into the textarea using the right-click context menu (Firefox 6).

Comment: @Kobi So much for the `paste` event working then. Same happened for me. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @mark - if it doesn't work at all (as compared to the special cases Kobi and I pointed out), please confirm where on your page you put the code - should be in the document ready function (or at least at the bottom after the textareas).

Comment: @alex: I don't know why but it prints `function(i, val) {
        return val.substr(0, 5);
    }` in text area every time.

Comment: @mark Are you using an old version of jQuery? I made an edit.

Comment: `$(this).val((function(i, val) {
    return val.substr(0, 5);
})());`

Comment: @ant What is your comment about?

Comment: @alex: I'm using Jquery 1.3. Is it good to use this version? Which version I should use?

Comment: @mark I would always use the latest if I had the choice. The latest is `1.6.2`.

Comment: @alex: which one should I download: `jQuery1.6.2.js` or `jQuery1.6.2-min.js` ?

Comment: @mark Use the minified one in a production environment. Better still, use the one hosted on [Google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery).

Comment: @alex fix for executing function and not writing it to textarea

Answer (score 0):

Horrible and aggressive way

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('textarea').each(function(){
        if (this.value.length > 5){
            this.value = this.value.substr(0,5);
        }
    })
}, 1)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YMsEF/

Comment: Solution is very resource-intensive

Comment: @ant_Ti, of course, I wouldn't say that this is **horrible** if it wasn't.

Answer (score -1):

```
var maxLettersCount = 3;

$('textarea').bind('keydown paste', function(event) {
    var textarea = $(event.target),
        text = textarea.val(),
        exceptionList = {
            8: true,
            37: true,
            38: true,
            39: true,
            40: true,
            46: true
        };

    if (event.type == 'keydown' && text.length >= maxLettersCount && !exceptionList[event.keyCode]) {
        return false;
    } else if (event.type == 'paste') {
        setTimeout(function() {
            textarea.val(textarea.val().substring(0, maxLettersCount));
        }, 1);
    }
})
```

Comment: in `events` you can add events keyCodes on which block shouldn't work

Comment: What if the user pastes (via keyboard, context menu or main menu)? What about drag'n'drop? And what's with the YES and NO constants?

Comment: `true` and `false` too trendy?