# Creating a textarea with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying create a text area in a div with the id of "body". I call the function with an onClick event, but when I click it, all that is created is *object HTMLTextAreaElement*. How can I get this to work?

```
function opentextarea() {
    var input = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'post');
    input.setAttribute('maxlength', 5000);
    input.setAttribute('cols', 80);
    input.setAttribute('rows', 40);
    var button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML=input, button;
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
var div = document.getElementById("yourDivElement");
var input = document.createElement("textarea");
var button = document.createElement("button");
input.name = "post";
input.maxLength = "5000";
input.cols = "80";
input.rows = "40";
div.appendChild(input); //appendChild
div.appendChild(button);
```

If you don't need to access specific DOM functions, I recommend to use innerHTML (because it's generally faster and less susceptible to memory leaks). Don't forget to properly deal with quotation marks. To keep the code readable, you can separate multiple lines by a plus sign:

```
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML =
   '<textarea maxlength="5000" cols="80" rows="40"></textarea>' + 
   '<button></button>"':
```

If you want to replace the contents, simply use `div.innerHTML = "";` before using the `appendChild` methods.

Answer (score 5):

You better assign the attributes directly, from what I remember IE got problems with `setAttribute`. The code can be changed to this in order to achieve what you want:

```js
function opentextarea() {
    var input = document.createElement('textarea');
    input.name = 'post';
    input.maxLength = 5000;
    input.cols = 80;
    input.rows = 40;
    input.className = 'myCustomTextarea';
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    var oBody = document.getElementById("body");
    while (oBody.childNodes.length > 0) {
        oBody.removeChild(oBody.childNodes[0]);
    }
    oBody.appendChild(input);
    oBody.appendChild(button);
 }
```

```css
.myCustomTextarea { color: red; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<div id="body">hello I will be replaced</div>
<button type="button" onclick="opentextarea();">Open</button>
```

By the way, `textarea` has no `maxlength` to limit characters you have to use JavaScript, for example: [How to impose maxlength on textArea in HTML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript)

Comment: The *Live test case* was awesome! Thank you

Comment: Cheers @Ibrahim glad to see it's still useful four years later! Embedded it now as a Stack Snippet to make it even more awesome. :-)

Comment: Hehe cool :P *in addition*, can you tell me though, how I can assign a class to the `textarea` that is created?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(input);
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(button);
```

Comment: well that's something, it adds it below the content, but I need it to replace the conent. Hence why I had .innerHTML getting somewhere though.

Comment: Add `div.innerHTML = "";` before the first `appendChild()`