# limit number of digits in label in html

Tags: html

is it possible to set limit of digits or words on label?

is there any way to limit the number of digits in label in html, i've searched on 
internet in every possible way, but didn't get any result..please help me frnds.

like on any textbox or textarea:

```
<textarea maxLength="10"></textarea>
```

OR

```
<input type="text" maxLength="10" />
```

BTW is it possible to cut the label after certain word limit through javascript?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript

Comment: Do you mean label? Or form input?

Comment: Label friends, actually the problem is that am calculating cart but when it adds some digits which end up with 9999 like characters it just spreads. so is there any way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

truncate label text before display in order to limit on length.

```
CSS solution:
  label{
    width:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

JS Solution:
  $('label:first').html().substr(0,13)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a label on might not need some of the following, but for a span, I needed to have the following:

```
span.yoyo {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

targetting

```
<span class="yoyo" title="The text here so that I can see on hovering">
  The text here so that I can see on hovering
</span>
```

Comment: I would really go for a css-only solution instead of relying on JS, because this is purely a presentation concern. Also, doing this in css allows automatic adaptation w.r.t. resizing of the element.

Comment: Also note I would always put title to be the entire text, so that one can see the hidden text as a "tooltip".

Answer (score 0):

`maxlength` for textarea's only works in HTML5, so you'll probably need to use Javascript.

The text input should work as you wrote it.

Also - how hard did you [search the Internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=textarea%20max%20length)?

Answer (score 0):

I see, so you want to write like a short description ...
Why don't you create a method which will return first 10 words or first 20 letters and then append dots?

Answer (score -1):

The only way todo this would be to use javascript to remove any characters after a certain limit.

What you could do is set the width of the label and hide any content that overflows this width using CSS:

```
label{
   max-width:100px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do this with js

Comment: I'm not sure the OP actually meant "label".