# Unable to Limit the user input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I tried limiting the user input but it wasn't successful, please guide me where I am making mistake.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function countLength() {
            var maxLength=10;
            var length = document.getElementById("txt").value.length;

            if(length>10) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

HTML code

```
 <form name="formA" id="formA" action="#" >
        <textarea id="txt" name="txt" onkeyup="countLength()"></textarea>
    </form>
```

Comment: here is a good solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Code looks ok to me. The event is raised and the length is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your code basically replicates the `maxlength` attribute, which seems to work (and I don't think is being deprecated?). Just use that.

```
<input type='text' name='mytext' maxlength='10'>
```

Comment: textareas have no maxlength. That's for input fields only.

Comment: Yea I know that but I also want to display message underneath `eg: 5 characters left` as in stackoverflow textbox

Answer (score 0):

`return false` on `onkeyup` does nothing (as you've probably noticed).  I've seen solutions where someone would just alter the value of the textarea, perform a substring operation, and assign that new value back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function countLength() {
        var maxLength=10;
        var ta = document.getElementById("txt");
        var length = ta.value.length;

        if(length>maxLength) {
            ta.value = ta.value.substr(0, maxLength); 
            return false;
        }
    }
```