# Create an event that removes on <div> element from view and creates a new <div> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to work out an experiment with a web based notepad. I have a textarea element that writes to a hidden div when the HTML page is printed. The issue I'm having is that the textarea element is allowed to overflow. My grand vision is to limit the textarea and once the textarea is filled, to have the filled div that holds it disappear from view, writing its contents to the hidden div used for printing, and a new div with a fresh textarea display.

Preferably, I'd like the user to have the option of clicking a button to perform this action, as well as performing the action automatically when the textarea is full.

Comment: Please don't include the last four paragraphs in your original question (see link: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15067688/revisions). They are useless noise.

Comment: well, you can listen to the keypress event and each time a key is pressed you can check whether textarea content's length has exceeded the text limit on it or not. If it has exceeded then using javascript you can hide that particular div and get the contents of the textarea and give it to another div for the printing.

Comment: with overflow, you mean multible lines (with possible linebreaks) ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check if the textarea overflows by using width and height. You can do it by setting maxlength. Again this attribute is not supported in all browsers. You might find this link helpful
[How to impose maxlength on textArea in HTML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript)