# ng-hide automatically triggering on field becoming invalid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a text area on which I have applied max length directive of angular:

```
<textarea placeholder="Quote text here" ng-model="quote.text" ng-maxlength="400" name="text"></textarea>
```

Now I am also showing the word count by using angular `ng-show` and `ng-hide` directive:

```
<div class="row word-count">
   <h5>Word count :</h5>
   <h5 ng-show="quote.text.length > 0">{{quote.text.length}}</h5> 
   <h5 ng-hide="quote.text.length > 0" class="ng-hide">0</h5>
</div>
```

the problem is that as soon as word count exceeds the max-length directive the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` are automatically triggered as reversed. Is there someway to stop it ?

Comment: Are you handling negative lengths?  Why have the ng-show and ng-hide? Just print out quote.text.length.  It will be 0 when there are no words, right? You just need to default text to empt string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the good-old HTML `maxlength`?

```
<textarea placeholder="Quote text here" ng-model="quote.text." name="text" maxlength="400"></textarea>

<div class="row word-count">
    <h5>Word count :</h5>
    <h5 ng-show="quote.text.length > 0">{{ quote.text.length }}</h5> 
    <h5 ng-hide="quote.text.length > 0" class="ng-hide">0</h5>
</div>
```

I personally don't understand the need for `ng-maxlength` since it just returns an error, but allows you to continue typing!

Comment: maxlength support for textarea element is quite new. Е.g. it doesn't work in IE8/IE9.

Comment: thanks for your input guys, as I am building a cordova app so it just needs to work in webkit

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior for angular validation. If validation fails, the corresponding model returns undefined.

You can try it on Angular site [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input).

Also, if you need to support IE8/IE9, [here is an example of own maxlength directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17076323/349782).