# Define maxlength for an html textarea

Tags: html, textarea, maxlength

I currently try to restrict the the maximal amount of characters allowed in a textarea.

With:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="50">
```

It works like it should in Firefox, however there seems to be no effect in IE which poses a problem since quite a lot of the website-users still use IE.

Do you have any suggestions or a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript to implement `maxlength` in Internet Explorer.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="50" onKeyPress="return(this.value.length < 50);">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting this since you had placed `php` in the tags, you can truncate the input from the server side using `substr`

```
$trunc = substr($_POST['textareaname'], 0, 50);
```

alternatively you can also use [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript/1125521#1125521) function.

UPDATE to your comment on how to provide a feedback to the user when limit is reached.

```
$("#element").keypress(function (e) {
    var str = $(this).val();
    if (str.length > 100) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('You have reached max limit');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to let the user know that he has reached the max-amount of chars? Because I basically want to stop the user from inputting more than 100 chars, in the code itself I already do the substr

Comment: yes you can, very simply if you use jquery. do you use jquery?