# maxlength attribute is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my js file inside a function, i m preparing like this

```
var x = '<span class="someclass">
         <textarea class="editField" maxlength="60">
         </textarea>      
         </span>';
```

here i m restricting the textarea size by using maxlength attribute,
it is not working in IE.

Comment: which IE version do you have? It only works in IE 10.

Comment: go to this link ,you will get your answer [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript

Comment: Hi mohkhan,this issue is in IE 7 & 8

Answer (score 1):

`maxlength` is not supported on `<textarea>` in all browsers. In any case, I don't think it's ever a good idea to actually restrain users from typing what they want. Tell them that they're over the limit, but don't lock them out.

Comment: actually, it is supported in some browser, check out here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp
note that only IE10 support it, IE9- (and older) will not

Comment: http://w3fools.com/, for one, but mainly I said "not [...] in all browsers", which means "yes in some browsers"

Comment: thanks Kolink and jim.but in my requirement i need to restrict the user.I added this onKeyPress="return (this.value.length < 60);"
 along with maxlength attribute.Now maxlength is working but there will be a problem if user copy paste the text

Answer (score 0):

it wouldn't.  IE10 now supports the HTML5 maxlength on a textarea.  [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp)  if you need to restrict length in previous IE versions then you'll need javascript for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maxlength is not supported in IE, If you want to restrict your users from entering unlimited characters in IE, you would need to use javascript for that.

You could use the below script to limit users from entering maximum characters in textarea forIE.

```
window.onload = function() { 
  var txts = document.getElementsByTagName('TEXTAREA') 

  for(var i = 0, l = txts.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(/^[0-9]+$/.test(txts[i].getAttribute("maxlength"))) { 
      var func = function() { 
        var len = parseInt(this.getAttribute("maxlength"), 10); 

        if(this.value.length > len) { 
          alert('Maximum length exceeded: ' + len); 
          this.value = this.value.substr(0, len); 
          return false; 
        } 
      }

      txts[i].onkeyup = func;
      txts[i].onblur = func;
    } 
  } 
}
```

And Your textarea can be like:

```
<textarea maxlength="10"></textarea>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fpYWF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The maxlength attribute is not standard for  in HTML 4.01. It is defined in HTML5 though but I guess IE doesn't implement it. To make it work across all browsers you could use javascript. Here's an example.please check this it may helps you..thank you

```
window.onload = function() { 
var txts = document.getElementsByTagName('TEXTAREA') 

for(var i = 0, l = txts.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(/^[0-9]+$/.test(txts[i].getAttribute("maxlength"))) { 
    var func = function() { 
    var len = parseInt(this.getAttribute("maxlength"), 10); 

    if(this.value.length > len) { 
      alert('Maximum length exceeded: ' + len); 
      this.value = this.value.substr(0, len); 
      return false; 
    } 
  }

   txts[i].onkeyup = func;
   txts[i].onblur = func;
  } 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually useless to restrain the user to type on his own end. This won't make any difference unless you don't test the length of what reaches the server (you really should).

I second what Kolink said, don't try to restrain the user from typing, but you can tell him that its input won't be accepted because it's exceeding.