# How to set the maxLength of a TextArea so that it works across all browsers?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, textarea, maxlength

I wrote the below maxLength restriction on the textarea control and it works fine in IE 9.0 but doesn't work with IE 8.0.

```
<textarea name="commentString" rows="7" maxlength="2000">some data </textarea>
```

How can I set the maxLength so that it works across all browsers? would JQuery have any helper method for this?

Comment: Similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript/1125521#1125521

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('textarea').keypress(function() {
  return $(this).val().length < 50;
});
```

Comment: if you're on the last letter then press back button then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It will not working below IE9.

Use this code it will work for below IE 9 version. only change version in if condtion.

```
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE .9")!=-1)
                                {
                                    $('#inputid').bind('keyup blur', function () {
                                        var $this = $(this);
                                        var len = $this.val().length;
                                        var maxlength = 3;
                                        if (maxlength && len > maxlength) {
                                            var inputvalue= $this.val().slice(0, maxlength);
                                            $this.val("");
                                            $this.val(inputvalue);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
```