# Javascript to auto calculate total character in input field

Tags: javascript, count, character

I have an issue that I'm trying to figure out.  This is what I have so far and it seems to work the way it was but when I add in a php variable to auto popuplate the input field, it doesn't seem to calculate the characters used.

This field has a max value of 80 characters which I cannot control.  I have to limit it ot 80 characters max.  I need the input field to aut calculate once the form loads and the field is populated.  When I include the php variable to the input value, the input field shows the field filled up with characters however, the field stays at "zero" characters until I move the mouse in the field and try to add another character.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.testform.countInput.focus();
function countChars(countfrom,displayto) {
  var len = document.getElementById(countfrom).value.length;
  document.getElementById(displayto).innerHTML = len;
}
</script>

<form id="testform">
Title: <strong id="countOutput">0</strong><strong>/80 Max Character</strong>
<input  type="text" name="dsp_URL" value="" size="80" maxlength="80"  lengthcut="true" id="countInput" onkeyup="countChars('countInput','countOutput');" /><br />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">


var input = document.getElementById ("countInput");
input.focus ();
</script>
<body>
</body>
</htmt>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any PHP, so it's not exactly clear what you're asking. Note that PHP is processed server-side, before any JavaScript runs. You can't use PHP code after the page is returned to the client.

Comment: Also, `document.getElementById(countfrom).value.length` != `document.getElementById(countfrom).value`

Comment: the php variable would go in the value="$url" which I left it out.  But it does not work when tested.

Comment: You need to do one of two things: (1) Output the length where you want it when the page loads (e.g., `<?php echo strlen($url); ?>`) or (2) call the JavaScript function on page load. It will be `0` or whatever you prepopulate it with until the JavaScript fires.

Comment: got it working guys.  thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the function on load of the page along with the `onkeyup` event

```js
document.testform.countInput.focus();

function countChars(countfrom, displayto) {
  var len = document.getElementById(countfrom).value.length;
  document.getElementById(displayto).innerHTML = len;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<form id="testform">
  Title: <strong id="countOutput">0</strong><strong>/80 Max Character</strong>
  <input type="text" name="dsp_URL" value="" size="80" maxlength="80" lengthcut="true" id="countInput" onkeyup="countChars('countInput','countOutput');" />
  <br />

  <script>
    countChars('countInput', 'countOutput');
  </script>

</form>

<body>
</body>
```

Just make sure to define the `countChars` before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is safe to assume that populating your text field with a string via php does not trigger the condition for countChars(), since its trigger is onkeyup on that text field.

Maybe you can find the solutions in [How to impose maxlength on textArea in HTML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript) helpful for your problem. I hope this helps your validation :)

Comment: is there a different event I could use to trigger it? I'm lost here.