# How to output a textarea in HTML to a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

In a HTML website I have a textarea created like this:

```
<textarea id = "myTextArea" rows = "30" cols = "80"></textarea>
```

I would like after something is written in the text area, for that text to be sent to a variable in javascript.

I have tried doing this, but it did not work:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
```

The `console.log(x);` gives back nothing, not null, just empty space. However, if I log out `console.log(document.getElementById("myTextArea").value)` then I get the text that I have written in my textarea.

Why does `var x = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;` not work?

My Javascript:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
const regex = /([a-z]+)/;
const match = regex.exec(x);

var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 500); <!-- Calls every 5s -->

function myCallback() {
    if(match){
       const name = match[1];
       console.log(name);
    }
    else{
       console.log('no match');
       console.log(match);
    }
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve] -> _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: Your textarea has no text so value is empty? The syntax looks ok to me.

Comment: In the beginning, yes, but even if I write something it still doesn't log anything.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you can register an event listener on your textarea:

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById('myTextArea');

textArea.addEventListener('input', function(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

The listener listens for any `input` events on your textara and logs the value of your textarea as the value changes.

Here's a [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tp4a1y0m/) for your quick reference.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `onkeyup` *and* `onchange` for this.  The onchange will prevent context-menu pasting, and the onkeyup will fire for every keystroke.

See my answer on [How to impose maxlength on textArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-javascript/1125521#1125521) for a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

In my example, the variable is the `text` variable. This variable is filled with the text of the text by clicking on the `button`.

Was it necessary?

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var text = "";

button.onclick = function() {
  text = x.value;
  console.log(text);
}
```

```css
#myTextArea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea" rows="30" cols="80"></textarea>
<button>Check variable with text</button>
```

Second example using `oninput` event.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
var text = "";

x.oninput = function() {
  text = this.value;
  console.log(text);
}
```

```css
#myTextArea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea" rows="30" cols="80"></textarea>
```