# Extjs messagebox prompt limit the text input entered by user

Tags: messagebox, extjs3

I am using http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/docs/output/Ext.MessageBox.html#prompt to display an extjs prompt where the user can enter some text and click Ok. Now if I want to restrict the user to enter text not more than 100 characters, what should I do?

I understand I need to write some kind of an eventhandler but what is the event? Is it possible to look at a code sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you invoke `MessageBox.prompt` it will return instance of the singleton which can be used to get dom reference of textbox element, this element can be used to specify attribute `maxlength` which can be used to limit length of text that can be entered

```
var dlg = Ext.MessageBox.prompt('Name', 'Please enter your name:', function(btn, text){
    if (btn == 'ok'){
        // process text value and close...
    }
});

var textboxEl = dlg.getDialog().body.child('input[class=ext-mb-input]', true);
textboxEl.setAttribute('maxlength', 1);   // second parameter is character length allowed so change it according to your need
```

**Reference:**

[Character Limit in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113376/character-limit-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Ext 4 (with many thanks to SilentSakky for the original answer):

```
var dlg = Ext.MessageBox.prompt('Name', 'Please enter your name:', function(btn, text){
    if (btn == 'ok'){
        // process text value and close...
    }
});

var textboxEl = dlg.getEl().query('input')[0];
textboxEl.setAttribute('maxlength', 1);
```