# How to enter only 10 numbers in input field?

Tags: angularjs, html

Ok i have input field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ticketPin">
```

I want to allow user to enter only numbers, 10 digts long(1234567890)

I tried with `type="number"` but thats not it. Any suggestion

EDIT: so i can use maxlength for 10 digits long, but what about to restrict only to numbers?
EDIT: pattern ="[0-9]*" is not working for me

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113376/character-limit-in-html

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `maxlength` attribute

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ticketPin" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: what about restrict to only numbers?

Comment: You need to use pattern `pattern="[0-9]*"` and additionally use `minlength="10"` as well if you want to make sure you enter exact 10 numbers.

Comment: hmm...its not working for me ...i still can enter letters

Comment: It works well for me. Can you share me the updated input element

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ticketPin" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]*">

Comment: Okay now, I got it. The pattern will not stop you from entering alphabets, however, will give you a validation error at the time of submit. You need to use `keyup` event in order to check.

Comment: its chrome...V43.0.2357.134 m

Comment: is there any way to prevent using anything other than letters on start?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83763/discussion-between-nikhil-and-uzhas).

Answer (score 3):

you can do this to make sure that entered value is number and is not more than 10 digit.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ticketPin" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="10">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//rawgit.com/candreoliveira/ngMask/master/dist/ngMask.min.js"></script>

  
</head>
<body ng-app="selectExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('selectExample', ['ngMask'])
  </script>
  <div>
     <input type='text' mask-clean='true' ng-model='ticketPin' mask='9999999999' restrict="reject" clean="true" />
  </div>
   {{ticketPin}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure user inputs only numbers, you can use `pattern` attribute:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ticketPin" pattern="[0-9]{10}">`

This technique will not work in all browsers, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern

Validation will be performed only in browser, don't forget to validate the data  again on server.

Comment: This will work but note that not all mobile devices are smart enough to trigger the numeric keyboard

Comment: True. Try type="number"  instead of type="text".

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;

}
```

```html
 <input id="Phone" onkeypress="return isNumeric(event)" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)" type="number" max = "9999999999" placeholder="Phone Number" />

<script>
  function maxLengthCheck(object) {
    if (object.value.length > object.max.length)
      object.value = object.value.slice(0, object.max.length)
  }
    
  function isNumeric (evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode (key);
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    if ( !regex.test(key) ) {
      theEvent.returnValue = false;
      if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
  }
</script>
```

jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/DharaPatel0621/mo9qgk31/