# How can I set a character limit for paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I currently have `<p>{{event.desc}}</p>` which gives the entire description of the event.

Some have very long description, and i only want, say, the first 50 characters.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: substr() - http://php.net/manual/bg/function.substr.php

Comment: are you using angularjs? if so, check this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Comment: I'm not using php. Is there not a HTML & CSS solution?

Comment: Using CSS, you can specify a max width and height for your paragraph, then you can use the CSS property [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) to cut off the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Character Limit in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113376/character-limit-in-html)

Comment: That's text input, I want it for a paragraph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.fifty-chars {
    width: 50ch;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p class="fifty-chars">Short event description</p>
<p class="fifty-chars">Long long long long long long long long long 
    long long long long long long long long long long long long long
    long event description</p>
```

Comment: I added one line of code in the CSS: `text-overflow: ellipsis;` which will give better optical results than a string truncated abruptly.

Answer (score 0):

in **PHP**

```
<?php
if (strlen($myString) > 20) {
echo substr($myString, 0, 20) . '...';
 } else {
echo $myString;
}
?>
```