# How to limit the numbers allowed in a numeric field

Tags: html, input

I want this field to be limited to maximum 3 numbers and that you can't type more

```
<input id="password_field_4" class="input_field" type="number" name="cvv" title="CVV" placeholder="CVV" max="3" >
```

What can I do? Do I need Javascript?

I already tried researching it, but didn't find anything helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Character Limit in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113376/character-limit-in-html)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-set-max-length-in-an-html5-input-type-number-element